# testing kafka and spark with testcontainers

Tags: scala, apache-spark, testcontainers, spark-kafka-integration

I am trying to check with testcontainers a streaming pipeline as a integration test but I don´t know how get bootstrapServers, at least in last testcontainers version and create a specific topic there. How can I use 'containerDef' to extract bootstrapservers and add a topic?

```
import com.dimafeng.testcontainers.{ContainerDef, KafkaContainer}
import com.dimafeng.testcontainers.scalatest.TestContainerForAll
import munit.FunSuite
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

class Mykafkatest extends FunSuite with TestContainerForAll {
  //val kafkaContainer: KafkaContainer      = KafkaContainer("confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.3")
  override val containerDef: ContainerDef = KafkaContainer.Def()

  test("do something")(withContainers { container =>
    val sparkSession: SparkSession = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("Unit testing")
      .getOrCreate()

    // How add a topic in that container?

    // This is not posible:
    val servers=container.bootstrapServers

    val df = sparkSession.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", servers)
      .option("subscribe", "topic1")
      .load()


    df.show(false)

  })

}
```

My sbt configuration:

```
lazy val root = project
  .in(file("./pipeline"))
  .settings(
    organization := "org.example",
    name := "spark-stream",
    version := "0.1",
    scalaVersion := "2.12.10",
    libraryDependencies := Seq(
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10"       % "3.0.3"  % Compile,
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql"                  % "3.0.3"  % Compile,
      "com.dimafeng"     %% "testcontainers-scala-munit" % "0.39.5" % Test,
      "org.dimafeng"     %% "testcontainers-scala-kafka" % "0.39.5" % Test,
      "org.scalameta"    %% "munit"                      % "0.7.28" % Test
    ),
    testFrameworks += new TestFramework("munit.Framework"),
    Test / fork := true
  )
```

Documentation does not show a complete example: https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/kafka/

Comment: Is the question related to MUnit (https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/latest/), MuleSoft's application testing framework to build automated tests for your Mule applications?

Comment: `container.getBootstrapServers()` does not work?

Comment: Not , it doesn`t

Comment: In absence of this test case, ideally how would you "Add a topic in that container?" Like how the flow works, what are methods available on contianer object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem here is that you are explicitly casting that `KafkaContainer.Def` to `ContainerDef`.

The type of container provided by `withContianers`, `Containter` is decided by `path dependent type` in provided `ContainerDef`,

```scala
trait TestContainerForAll extends TestContainersForAll { self: Suite =>

  val containerDef: ContainerDef

  final override type Containers = containerDef.Container

  override def startContainers(): containerDef.Container = {
    containerDef.start()
  }

  // inherited from TestContainersSuite
  def withContainers[A](runTest: Containers => A): A = {
    val c = startedContainers.getOrElse(throw IllegalWithContainersCall())
    runTest(c)
  }

}
```

```scala
trait ContainerDef {

  type Container <: Startable with Stoppable

  protected def createContainer(): Container

  def start(): Container = {
    val container = createContainer()
    container.start()
    container
  }
}
```

The moment you explicitly specify the type `ContainerDef` in `override val containerDef: ContainerDef = KafkaContainer.Def()`, this breaks the whole "type trickery" and thus Scala compiler is left with a `type Container <: Startable with Stoppable` instead of a `KafkaContainer`.

So, just remove that explicit type cast to `ContainerDef`, and that `val servers = container.bootstrapServers` will work as expected.

```scala
import com.dimafeng.testcontainers.KafkaContainer
import com.dimafeng.testcontainers.munit.TestContainerForAll
import munit.FunSuite

class Mykafkatest extends FunSuite with TestContainerForAll {
  override val containerDef = KafkaContainer.Def()

  test("do something")(withContainers { container =>
    //...

    val servers = container.bootstrapServers

    println(servers)

    //...
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you give more details? this code does not compiles

Comment: Do you mean the `Mykafkatest` code in the answer ? What compilation error are you getting ?

Comment: added proper imports. Note that we need to import `com.dimafeng.testcontainers.KafkaContainer` and not `org.testcontainers.containers.KafkaContainer`.

Comment: well now it is not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/dimafeng/testcontainers-scala-kafka_2.12/0.39.5/testcontainers-scala-kafka_2.12-0.39.5.pom and really in this url  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ does not exists 'dimafeng' folder

Comment: Why are you looking for that folder at that url ? `"com.dimafeng" %% "testcontainers-scala-munit" % "0.39.5"` is clrealy available at maven central - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.dimafeng/testcontainers-scala-munit_3/0.39.5 . `sbt` will automatically downlod and add this to your project. Do you have some problem in your sbt project ?

Comment: container.bootstrapServers is not a correct method.

Comment: Did you try the code which I have provided in my answer ? Or are you talking about your code ? Just copy-paste the code in my answer and try running that.

Comment: you are right, it works, sorry